# Software for cutting GIF?

Tags: software-recommendation, gif

Is there a software from the official repositories that can cut GIFs?
For example, if given a GIF that runs for 20s, the software should be able to extract the last 5s from it.

I prefer GUIs, but if there are none, command line tools are fine too.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Perhaps this might be useful: https://askubuntu.com/q/870855/57576